# Using grep to extract data from a txt file in R

Tags: r

For a class i have to find a bunch of different prices for a type of car per model year. We were told to just use cars.com and copy and paste all the text into a notepad txt file once we narrowed down the seach. Then just save it and use:

grep '\$' tmpHondaCRV2012.txt  > hondaCRV2012.txt

I'm not a programmer so i really have no idea that that means, but i knew at least to save my file correctly and to type it all in right but it keeps giving me the error message "'\$' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "'\$"" ... and i have no idea what that means. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This grep command is to be entered in a terminal on Linux, not in the R console.

However you can enter in the R console this way, if you are on Linux:

```
system("grep '\\$' tmpHondaCRV2012.txt > hondaCRV2012.txt")
```

If you want to take the values directly from the web:

```
install.packages('XML')
library(XML)
html.raw<-htmlTreeParse(
  'http://www.cars.com/for-sale/searchresults.action?dlId=&dgId=&AmbMkNm=Honda&AmbMdNm=Civic&AmbMkId=20017&AmbMdId=20823&searchSource=ADVANCED_SEARCH&rd=100000&zc=02747&uncpo=2&cpo=&stkTyp=U&VType=&mkId=20017&mdId=20823&alMkId=20017&prMn=&prMx=&clrId=&yrMn=1997&yrMx=1997&drvTrnId=&mlgMn=&mlgMx=&transTypeId=&kw=&kwm=ANY&ldId=&rpp=100&slrTypeId=',
  useInternalNodes=T
)
html.parse<-xpathApply(html.raw, "//span[@class='priceSort']", xmlValue)
values <- unlist(html.parse)
```

Comment: This just gave me the message: > system("grep '\\$' tmpHondaCRV2012.txt > hondaCRV2012.txt")
Warning message:
running command 'grep '\$' tmpHondaCRV2012.txt > hondaCRV2012.txt' had status 127

Comment: What it does, is that it goes through the lines of the tmpHondaCRV2012.txt file, and prints a line only if it contains the $ character. The result will be in hondaCRV2012.txt.

Comment: As in what's status 127?

Comment: What's your operating system? It seems like you do not have the grep command.

Comment: I really just want to extract all the price values from this page: http://www.cars.com/for-sale/searchresults.action?dlId=&dgId=&AmbMkNm=Honda&AmbMdNm=Civic&AmbMkId=20017&AmbMdId=20823&searchSource=ADVANCED_SEARCH&rd=100000&zc=02747&uncpo=2&cpo=&stkTyp=U&VType=&mkId=20017&mdId=20823&alMkId=20017&prMn=&prMx=&clrId=&yrMn=1997&yrMx=1997&drvTrnId=&mlgMn=&mlgMx=&transTypeId=&kw=&kwm=ANY&ldId=&rpp=100&slrTypeId=   ...... If you knew an easier way to do it on r that would be fine